# to_smt2() for Optimize class

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

Is there a function to_smt2() for Optimize class which does the same thing as the function with the same name in Solver class, that us create an smt-lib file with the optimization problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
from z3 import *

o = Optimize ()
i = Int('x')
o.add (i > 5)
o.add (i < 10)
o.maximize(i)
print o.sexpr()
print o.check()
print o.model()
```

This prints:

```
$ python a.py
(declare-fun x () Int)
(assert (> x 5))
(assert (< x 10))
(maximize x)
(check-sat)

sat
[x = 9]
```

Note that `maximize` is not an SMTLib function, but a z3 extension.